# python function incrementing variable in list for no obvious reason

Tags: python, list, increment

so I'm new to Python, and I've got this issue I don't understand. Here's the code:

(enemy and playerPos are both lists containing 2 variables, e.g. [1,2] )

```
def AIenemyTurn(enemy,playerPos):
    startPos = enemy
    print(startPos)
    potEnemyPos = enemy
    if playerPos[0] > enemy[0]:
        potEnemyPos[0] += 1
    elif playerPos[0] < enemy[0]:
        potEnemyPos[0] -= 1
    elif playerPos[1] > enemy[1]:
        potEnemyPos[1] += 1
    elif playerPos[1] < enemy[1]:
        potEnemyPos[1] -= 1
    if potEnemyPos not in rocks:
        print(potEnemyPos)
        print(startPos)
        return potEnemyPos
    else:
        return startPos
```

this is what shows up in the Shell:

```
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2]
```

why is startPos different the second time it gets printed? I haven't modified it at all in the function

Comment: I am not sure what the logic for the game is, but `elif playerPos[1] > enemy[1]` etc. will never be evaluated unless `playerPos[0] == enemy[0]`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because lists are mutable, so assigning them to two different values means both those values refer to the same list:

```
>>> x = [2, 2]
>>> y = x
>>> z = x
>>> z[1] = 0
>>> z
[2, 0]
>>> y
[2, 0]
```

You can also check by seeing the `id`s:

```
>>> id(y)
4300734408
>>> id(z)
4300734408
>>> id(x)
4300734408
>>>
```

A way to get around this is by calling `startPos = list(enemy)`, as casting to `list` makes a new list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> id(a)
4300922320
>>> id(b)
4300922680
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
def AIenemyTurn(enemy,playerPos):
    startPos = list(enemy)
    print(startPos)
    potEnemyPos = enemy
    if playerPos[0] > enemy[0]:
        potEnemyPos[0] += 1
    elif playerPos[0] < enemy[0]:
        potEnemyPos[0] -= 1
    elif playerPos[1] > enemy[1]:
        potEnemyPos[1] += 1
    elif playerPos[1] < enemy[1]:
        potEnemyPos[1] -= 1
    if potEnemyPos not in rocks:
        print(potEnemyPos)
        print(startPos)
        return potEnemyPos
    else:
        return startPos
```